# Integrating Stack Blur C++ Port to iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, blur

Can anybody give me a pointer as to how to integrate the Stack Blur C++ library to Objective C?

http://antigrain.com/index.html

It's probably straightforward. I used to be a C programmer long, long time ago and now I'm comfortable enough with Objective C but I completely bypassed C++ so it gives me a headache just looking at the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation of Stack Blur for iOS somebody else created:

https://github.com/tomsoft1/StackBluriOS

I'm sure it'll come in handy for some people.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look at the docs regarding "Objective-C++". Basically, you can semi-freely intermix Obj-C and C++ with a few restrictions. The main one is that Obj-C classes can't inherit from C++ or vice versa. You can have C++ members in an obj-c class, and vice versa, because it's just pointers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up porting Box Blur written in Java because that's all I needed.

Comment: @Yong - Any chance you'd like to contribute your port? I'm about to do the same exact thing, and would save me a ton of time. :)

Comment: Mark, sorry I didn't get back to you sooner. If you're still interested please pm me. I don't have the author's permission so I don't want to publish it here.